# Receiving images dynamically from backend with unknown filetypes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Dear fellow Stackoverflow-Users,

I recently had gotten the requirement to dynamically load images from the backend into my application. Until recently - since it was never specified in any other way in the documentation or otherwise - I assumed we were always SVG images. That worked out spendidly, because I had a rough idea what to do to begin with.

```
getGmaLogo(gmaId) {

this.httpClient.get(ApiUrls.QA_GMA_LOGO + "/" + gmaId, { headers: this.authHeader, responseType: "text" })
  .pipe(catchError(error => {
  // Those are merely my own error messages 
    this.errorService.showError(error);
    return this.errorService.handleError(error);
  }))
  .subscribe(image => {         

    let base64EncodedString = window.btoa(image)

    this.gmaLogo = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + s);
  })
```

}

And then added it to my page like this.

```
<img [src]="gmaService.gmaLogo || ''" alt="Company Name"/>
```

But alas, things never turn out easy, do they?

In fact, I may receive jpeg, png and so on. Apparently, it would inconvenience people if they had to settle for SVG only icons. Which leads to my question... can I dynamically infer from the response I receive what data-type I have available without setting a specific response type in the headers? Leaving it blank doesn't work, because as we know, the default responsetype is JSON.

Comment: why does it matter? do the image actually show up on screen when you set the img.src attribute or not? Because images should be displayed even though you don't know the filetype if it is an image. In the data URL just put image/octet-stream instead of whatever type you put before .

Comment: It works fine with SVGs. They're getting rendered but of course it doesn't work when I change the response type to something else. I mean, I somehow have to know what kind of file I receive from the backend, so I can properly create the appropriate src url. I only get an error message when I change the response type to something else.

Comment: You might be able to infer the data-type from the response headers (https://angular.io/api/http/Response)

Comment: Chris, that's deprecated BUT it's a good idea altogether. It led me to the typechecking of responses, so I might be able to do something with that. If it works out, I'll write an appropriate response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, I use `Blob` response type in client-side and don't care about the type of file. This works like expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yuy5km

**Service**

```
getGmaLogo(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
  return this.httpClient.get(imageUrl, {headers: this.authHeader, responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

**Component**

To create an image from Blob, I used `FileReader` to read the contents of `Blob`

```
imageToShow: any;

createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
   let reader = new FileReader();
   reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      this.imageToShow = reader.result;
   }, false);

   if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
   }
}
```

Next, you get the image from the service

```
getImageFromService() {
      this.imageService.getImage(yourImageUrl).subscribe(data => {
        this.createImageFromBlob(data);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img [src]="imageToShow" />
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The DOM sanitizer immediately springs to action. Adding a screenshot link in a bit

Comment: My answer doesn't use DOM sanitizer. getImageFromService subscribe the service.

Comment: That's what threw me off why your application works. I basically copied your code and got this as a result: https://imgur.com/UPq9hcR

Comment: answer updated. I don't care about the type returned by API server and use DOM sanitizer. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Okay, this seems to have been a genuine error on my end. It works! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you. Blob determine itself the type for you: